# Магнитный электрогенератор: Будет работать непрерывно долго?

Tags: проектирование, физика, проект

Сегодня наверно каждый человек на Земле, слышал хотя бы раз о мировых проблемах в сфере энергоресурсов и связанных с этим проблемами глобального потепления...

Насмотревшись в YouTube разных аматорских решений получения "зелёной" энергии, решил набросать схему, как я вижу реализацию магнитного электрогенератора. Теперь возник вопрос: Будет ли оно так работать? :) Как вы думаете, будет ли работать такая схема непрерывно долго, вырабатывая электроэнергию? Какие есть программные решения для симуляции подобных моделей без конструирования рабочего макета?

Конструктивно похожий [пример магнитного электрогенератора можно посмотреть на YouTube](https://youtu.be/92nsAaMvQcs?t=371).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Теория суха, мой друг, но зеленеет жизни древо". Так что, надо сделать и посмотреть, что получится.

Comment: Что значит «непрерывно долго»? Очередной [вечный двигатель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin "надо сделать и посмотреть" - да вот, добавил уточнение к вопросу: Какие есть программные решения для симуляции подобных моделей без конструирования рабочего макета?

Comment: Что значит «непрерывно долго»? - пока магниты не размагнитятся :) Задумка именно такая. И именно поэтому взяты углы 120 градусов, которые в сумме образуют 4Пи; с каждого угла образуется треугольник, который делится на 2 равных треугольника через биссектрису (высоту)... То есть основная идея - это  "суперпозиция".

Comment: Генератор, показанный в ролике, будет работать пока не сядут батарейки в подставке)

Comment: *"на захламленном верстаке крутится, поскрипывает вечный двигатель. Маленький, опытная модель. Двигатель крутился второй месяц, только в плохую погоду отсыревал, и его приходилось тогда подталкивать рукой"* (с) Кир Булычев И еще — ***не учите физику, и жизнь ваша будет полна чудес...***

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял схему, то он не только не будет работать бесконечно долго, но и не будет работать вообще. Для приведения в движение вращающейся части нужны переменные магниты, а не постоянные. При постоянных колесо просто не станет вращаться - оно встанет в точку равновесия почти сразу.

Подробный разбор тут: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sT_bTnkwLuE.

В физике только изолированные системы могут работать бесконечно долго. Как только ты начинаешь что-то из системы забирать, она постепенно перестаёт работать как раньше.

Купи простенький ручной генератор за пару долларов и ещё нагрузку за доллар и попробуй покрутить ручку без нагрузки и с нагрузкой - ты удивишься, насколько ощутима разница.

[image: фото устройства]

Comment: "Для приведения в движение вращающейся части нужны переменные магниты" - в данной схеме переменное давление магнитных полей в зависимости от расстояния.
"Как только ты начинаешь что-то из системы забирать, она постепенно перестаёт работать как раньше." - полезная нагрузка описывается свойствами магнита, характеризующих поля постоянных магнитов (до 1Тл  или 10 кГс). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82

Comment: `не будет работать вообще` Ага, вот ты и попался, очередной участник Всемирного Заговора Нефтяных Магнатов против альтернативных бесконечных источников энергии!

Comment: Президент России В.В.Путин **"нам нужно переходить на газомоторное топливо"** https://youtu.be/lhVF0vKXAmk?t=88 Следующий ответ от @Zhihar **"ваша схема идентично вот этим известным"** - вообще абсурд с переводом темы на термоядерные реакторы, в частности к российским интересам термоядерной установки "ТОКАМАК" во Франции: https://twitter.com/VideoSound/status/1453649706077335560?s=20

Answer (score 0):

согласно первому закону термодинамики непрерывно и неограниченно долго он работать не будет, будет достигнуто равновесие при повороте < 60 градусов (в зависимости от начального положения)

ваша схема идентично вот этим известным уже давно схемам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А решение энергетического кризиса - это термоядерные реакторы и сверхпроводящие линии электропередач.